# I cant install gnome classic or the shell one

Tags: gnome, themes, command-line, gnome-classic

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information...Done
Package gnome-shell is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'gnome-shell' has no installation candidate
```

Same message over and over, this is a fresh install

Answer (score 0):

Have you run `sudo apt-get update` yet?

You need to do that on a fresh install or it doesn't know where things are.

Comment: Yes I just ran it and it did not help.